# MySQL (InnoDB) shutsdown same time every day

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql, webserver

Ok so recently pushed a large update to my project onto my Ubuntu 14 server.

Up until now it's been stable however since the push at exactly **00:36 GMT each day** mysql is killed!! Not ideal as we need as much uptime as possible. I've ramped up error logging to see if I can catch it next time.

### Not Resource Related, I don't Think...

I have checked the following:

- Server resources. Nothing spikes, it's steady and more than enough RAM available ~200mb free at least. Using Scoutapp to track this.
- No crons are running at that exact time.
- The `key_buffer_size` was 16M i just put it to 32MB. But can't see anything that would be causing this.

### Error Log

However I have checked the logs at the time of the crash and this is what is in there:

```
141123 00:36:47 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0 
141123 00:36:47 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
141123  0:36:48 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead. 
141123  0:36:48 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead. 
141123  0:36:48 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead. 
141123  0:36:48 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. 
141123  0:36:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled 
141123  0:36:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 
141123  0:36:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8 
141123  0:36:48 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO 
141123  0:36:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12 
141123  0:36:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
141123  0:36:48 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool 
141123  0:36:48 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error. 
141123  0:36:48 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed. 
141123  0:36:48 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB 
141123  0:36:48 [ERROR] Aborting

141123  0:36:48 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

141123 00:36:48 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

### So Does this mean...?

Does this mean that the InnoDB engine needs configured. I realised the my.cnf variables need altered but those are just warnings.

`Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool` makes me think that I need to set a buffer pool size for InnoDB which is smaller, if so how?

In addition, this was not happening before the update. But the VPS only has 512mb RAM and the traffic is growing and the application complexity especially with the new update.

What I don't understand is why it happens the *exact* same time each day. Does Ubuntu run updates or is there a schedule on Ubuntu I should know about, perhaps that's using up the memory?

Thanks

-Stefan

Comment: what's the output of `at`?

Comment: If you still have problems with innodb, let me know, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you need to check the below provided in your server.

1. Whether any cron is running in the server. You can make use of cron job log file to verify that. The log file is at the path : /var/log/syslog
2. Checking the load average at that specific time will also help you if there is any other load consuming process was initiated at that time. You can check the syslog at the location /var/log to trace it out.
3. Try reducing your key_buffer_size to 1MB and watch if it is still getting crashed.
   If still getting crashed upgrading RAM should be the final option.
4. I also recommend that you run a mysqltuner script and let me know the output.